# Jhipster: How can I only generate a back-end microservice application

Tags: jhipster

I want to generate microservices application with only Back-end code.
I found solution in [this](https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/).
And I used **jhipster --skip-client** but It's still have some Font-end files like node-modules,packege.json...

After that, I found another solution instead of **jhipster --skip-client** . I use jhipster:server and it works . I didn't have any Font-End file,but I could run by use **mvnw** . This is my error

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.184 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-08T16:20:28+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) on project test-mic: Properties could not be loaded from File: C:\Users\DatNT80\Desktop\TestMic\sonar-project.properties -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can I resolve my problem

Comment: could you please paste a more content from the output?

Answer (score 2):

`jhipster --skip-client` is the correct way to generate a server only application. By invoking `jhipster server`, you are using an internal "jhipster sub-generator" which will likely result in an incomplete or even non working application.

The package.json and node_modules are not frontend files. They are required to locally install jhipster as a JavaScript dependency of your project (jhipster is coded in JS). This way when invoking jhipster in your app directory, it is garanteed to use the same jhipster version as the one your app was generated with.